# How to Install Subclipse in ofline mode?

Tags: svn, flash-builder, subclipse

I am trying to install Subclipse with Flash Builder 4, but the problem is that this machine is not connected to the net.

Hence I downloaded the zipped files from : http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=2240

When I extract this into a folder & use it as a repository, I can see the packages, but cannot install the plugins due to "missing requirement subversion revision graph 1.0.9"

Has anyone installed Subclipse in ofline mode successfully?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a known problem.

- [Eclipse error report](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/error/report/16331)
- [subclipse discussion](http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1047&dsMessageId=2361695)

It looks like you need to have Eclipse GEF plugin installed prior to doing an offline subclipse install.

Answer (score 0):

The simple option is to simply de-select the optional Revision Graph plugin.  You could also download the offline installer for GEF/Draw2D and install it first.

Note the same problem would happen with the optional Subclipse Mylyn integration plugin if Mylyn was not already installed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see the option for unchecking Revision Graph Plugin.